# Is there a way to timeout functions inside mapAsync for akka?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am trying to do asynchronous http calls with akka streams.

This is what I tried.

```scala
Source(listEndpoints)
      .mapAsync(20)(endpoint => Future(Await.result(request(HttpMethods.POST, endpoint, List(authHeader)), timeout)))
      .runWith(Sink.seq[HttpResponse])
```

I am using `akka-http` within the request method and it returns `Future[HttpResponse]`

I think I am abusing `Future` here. The code above would give me a `Future[List[HttpResponse]]` and I have to use `Await` again to get a `List[HttpResponse]`. Is there a more elegant way to timeout functions within `mapAsync`?

Comment: Why do you need to await? Why not mapping on that result?

Comment: I am still learning akka streams, so bear with me. Source emits one output. What I understand is that `.mapAsync(20)` would get 20 such output and then fire 20 http request parallelly. Lets say I do a map, instead of `.mapAsync`, it would take each emitted output one by one and fire a request. Now I have to do a await on the resulting `Future[List[HttpResponse]]`  with a huge timeout?

Comment: It is not related to the requests you are doing. Even the return type of `Source(1 to 10).runWith(Sink.seq[Int])` is `Future[Seq[Int]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `request` method at some point does

```
Http().singleRequest
```

to get a `Future[HttpResponse]`, you can pass a timeout for the request through:

```
// inside def request(...), will probably need to add a timeout argument here
val request = ???  // Build the HttpRequest
Http().singleRequest(
  request = request,
  settings = ConnectionPoolSettings.default.withMaxConnectionLifetime(timeout)
```

Then your stream would just be

```
Source(listEndpoints)
  .mapAsync(request(...))
  .runWith(Sink.seq[HttpResponse])
```

and you'd only need to `Await` at the "end of the world" for the `Future[List[HttpResponse]]` to complete.

You can also change the default max connection lifetime with `akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-connection-lifetime` in `application.conf`

Comment: Where in akka docs is this explained? OMG!! Does this mean I can probably do a retry as well?

Comment: The config setting is documented at https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/timeouts.html and the whole `ConnectionPoolSettings` bit is from the scaladoc (it's not mentioned afaict in the high-level docs).

Comment: Since the request-level client builds on the host-level client, it's possible that for connections to the same host/port combo, they'll share a connection and leverage HTTP pipelining; if that's the case and some of your endpoints are hitting the same host/port, you might have premature timeout issues.